# Apache NIFI The request contained an invalid host header

Tags: docker, apache-nifi, rancher

I am trying to run Apache NIFI on a docker in my Rancher server. Rancher is running correclty as I have other services running. It is installed on a Debian box.

I am trying to test the official Apache Nifi container. As rancher's default port is 8080, I am trying to run it on another port. I am trying to run the first command as it is referenced in the documentation:

```
docker run --name nifi -p 9090:9090 -d -e NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT='9090' apache/nifi:latest
```

This gives me the error I mentioned in the title:

```
The request contained an invalid host header [xx.xx.xx.xx:9090] in the request [/nifi]. Check for request manipulation or third-party intercept.
```

I have tried to run it on a ubuntu laptop where docker is freshly installed and it started without problems.

If I get to the docker command line with `docker exec -it nifi bash` I see that I have no vi, nano nor any way of editing the nifi configuration file where I am supposed to change that information.

I have tried to create it directly from the rancher interface but it stays for a very long time just starting the container.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache NiFi 1.6.0 was [just released (April 8, 2018)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Version1.6.0) and the Docker image should update within the next few days to refer to that version. In 1.6.0, the host header handling was relaxed to be more user-friendly:

- [NIFI-4761](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4761) Host headers are not blocked on unsecured instances (i.e. unless you have configured TLS, you won't see this message anymore)
- [NIFI-4761](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4761) A new property in `nifi.properties` (`nifi.web.proxy.host`) was added to allow for listing acceptable hostnames that are not the `nifi.web.http(s).host`
- [NIFI-4788](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4788) The Dockerfile was updated to allow for this acceptable listing via a parameter like `NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST='someotherhost.com'`

I'm not familiar with Rancher, but I would think the container would have some text editor installed.

Comment: The docker image I am using is not rancher specific, so the fact that i was not able to find vi nor nano (I am cautious about saying it is not there :) ) is referedb to the apache/nifi image published in the docker hub. Anyway, I have bypassed the problem by placing the configuration files in a volume, which I beleive to be a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Rancher through the Web itnerface and after a LONG wait has managed to start the container and it works.

I still don't know why on the command line it is not working, but now it is secondary.